# Vue i18n and dynamic routes (Possibly of infinite redirection Error)

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-i18n

I try to use a small bilanguage vue app with vue-i18n. I used [this tutorial](https://lokalise.com/blog/vue-i18n/) but will include the relevant code snippets here.
Everything was fine until I added a dynamic route to the router.
It currently contains the following routes:

```
import Tr from '@/i18n/translation';

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/:locale?',
      component: RouterView,
      beforeEnter: Tr.routeMiddleware,
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          name: 'home',
          component: HomeView,
        },
        {
          path: '/:locale?/:artist',
          name: 'artists',
          component: () => import('../views/ArtistView.vue'),
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
});
```

Then there is my routeMiddleware, which looks like the following:

```
  async routeMiddleware(to, _from, next) {
    const paramLocale = to.params.locale;
    if (!Trans.isLocaleSupported(paramLocale)) {
      return next(Trans.guessDefaultLocale());
    }
    await Trans.switchLanguage(paramLocale);
    return next();
  },

  async switchLanguage(newLocale) {
    Trans.current_locale = newLocale;
    document.querySelector('html').setAttribute('lang', newLocale);
    localStorage.setItem('user-locale', newLocale);
  },
```

When I am on my route /en/artist-1 everything works well. When I go back to /en oder /de, it also works well. But when I hard reload or enter the page through this, it throws the following error:

```
 Unexpected error when starting the router: Error: Infinite redirect in navigation guard
```

Also when I watch the route, it returns an empty object for params at /en or /de.

Do you have any idea what causes the infinite redirect and how to fix it?